# Will I throw a balanced and blueprinted engine out of balance by gluing magnets to the harmonic balancer?

Tags: ignition, crankshaft

I want to measure the position of the crankshaft with my homemade car computer and compare it to the signal from the no. 1 spark plug so I can measure the engine timing while driving. I was thinking the best way to do this would be to use JB Weld and glue 2 magnets to either side of the harmonic balancer so there would be 1 magnet at the 0 degrees TDC and another 180 off. Then use a hall-effect switch mounted near the magnets. Of course, I would be getting 4 signals from my make-shift CPS for every signal from the no. 1 spark plug, but the firmware would have to account for that.

Comment: Does your harmonic balancer have a hall effect sensor anywhere on the perimeter? If so, magnets will possibly cause damage to the engine by throwing off the timing.

Comment: I forgot to mention: it's a 1977 Ford F150 so no, there is no other sensors nearby.

Comment: If you get them exactly opposite each other then it will be fine - make sure they are the same mass...

Comment: I would be VERY cautious about "glueing" anthing onto rotating parts of the engine - not because of the risk of unbalancing the engine if you attach equal and opposite masses, but because of the centripetal forces involved. If your sensor is about 1 inch off the rotation axis, and the shaft is doing 6000 RPM, the *apparent* weight of the sensor will be about *1000 times* its actual weight. The force trying to pull a 1-ounce magnet off the shaft will be about 60 pounds, not one ounce. Is your glue good enough to handle that?

Comment: @alephzero I did this years ago on an Audi to make the petrol engine rev counter work on a diesel engine. Simple trick is to stick the magnets to the INSIDE face of the pulley, then the forces are not acting to pull it off. Just have to orient the sensor...

Comment: So the hall-effect switch on the outside of the pulley can detect the magnets on the inside? (guess there's one way to find out...)

Comment: I would avoid changing the harmonic balancer in anyway.  There will have been a lot of design put into making it work correctly.  If you do some research you will find that a lot of damage can occur if it is not doing its job.  You may even make it worse than not having one.  Why not add a bit of white paint and use an infra red emitter/detector instead.

Comment: @SpaceCowboy I did say at the end of my coment “just have to orient the sensor” and I managed it for my Audi, and yes, the magnets were on the inside of the pulley and so was the sensor - with shielded wires going to the circuit (basically a decoder to simulate a coil low voltage to drive the tacho).

Comment: Why take a chance? IR detector sounds like the way to go.

Comment: @SpaceCowboy So, why not do it properly, since you say it is so well balanced and calculate the primary and secondary forces both with and without the magnets included - what's the betting the difference will be in about the 3rd decimal place...

Comment: @SpaceCowboy "So the hall-effect switch on the outside of the pulley can detect the magnets on the inside? It depends what the pulley is made of. (but I guess it's not going to be cast iron!)

Comment: @SolarMike " what's the betting the difference will be in about the 3rd decimal place..." It doesn't matter what the *resultant* forces are, if the forces on the individual parts are big enough to break something. But gluing the sensors on the *inside* of a flange is a good move, since it means the "60 pound force" is compressing the adhesive and not shearing it. Of course it *is* possible to design such things so they work - I've even see a complete self-powered radio transmitter attached to something rotating at 20,000 RPM.

Comment: @alephzero and some just magnetize the nut holding the vanes on a turbo shaft so they can measure 180000 rpm...

Comment: I originally wanted to mount a missing tooth wheel on it but thought this would be too unstable: https://photos.shutterfly.com/album/100230046330